# How to return an object from a pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently new to coding in C++ and I am having trouble with the pointers. I am making a suduko solver which has a cell class and a cell group class. The cell class has methods which sets the cells value, whether it is an original or given number and multiple methods considering the candidate list (the list of possible numbers the value may be). The `CellGroup` class has been created so I can have `CellGroup`s of 9 to check through, for the rows, columns and 3x3 blocks.

I have currently managed to read in the suduko from a file, and populate the cellgroups accordingly. Here is how the cell and the groups are set:

The cell:

```
Cell::Cell(int value, bool given)
{
    if (given == true)
    {
        m_given = true;
    }
    else {
        m_given = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { //1 to 9
            if (i != value) { //if i does not equal the value 
                m_candidateList.push_back(i);  //populate the candidate list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the cell group class:

```
void CellGroup::setCell(int index, Cell *cell)
{
    m_cells[index] = cell;
}
```

This seems to be working fine when initializing the grid and adding the cells.

My problem at the moment is I am trying to now retrieve these cells, so I can get there values and ultimately try to get a solution.

I have a method in the `CellGroup` class to retrieve the cell:

```
Cell* CellGroup::returnCell(int index)
{
    Cell *cell = m_cells[index];
    return cell;
}
```

And methods in the cell class to get the value in the cell as well as if the number has been given:

```
int Cell::getValue(void) const
{
    return m_value;
}

bool Cell::getIsGiven(void) const
{
    if (m_given == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However in the puzzle class, when I try to retrieve a cells value or whether it has been given or not, it is returning obscure values. I think the pointer is returning an address, and I am unsure on how I can obtain the actual object. Here is what I have currently tried:

```
void SudokuPuzzle::TryToSolve()
{
    Cell* cell = m_gridRows[1].returnCell(1);
    Cell newCell = *cell;
    int val = newCell.getValue;
    cout << val << endl;
    bool given = newCell.getIsGiven;
    cout << given << endl;
}
```

Apologies if the answer is quite obvious, I am extremely new to C++ and using pointers.

Any advice/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not understanding it correctly, but can't you pass around pointers and then just dereference them when you need value?

Comment: You need to dereference pointers to objects, to call member functions on them. Or just use `->` operator, which does said dereference implicitly.

Comment: `bool given = newCell.getIsGiven;` you seem to be missing some parentheses there. And if that didn't flag a compiler warning of some kind perhaps raise your warning levels to pedantic levels. And on that note: `bool given = cell->getIsGiven();` and get rid of `newCell` entirely. Unrelated, `getIsGiven` should just `return m_given;`, and least-important, vernacular suggestion: call the member `isGiven()`.

Comment: Thank you, how would I go about dereferencing them and would I do this in the try to solve method??

Comment: @KlasLindbäck `newCell` isn't a pointer. Pretty sure you mean `cell`.

Comment: Hi I changed my code to this and I still seem to be getting an obscure result:

Comment: Cell* cell = m_gridRows[1].returnCell(1);
 int value = cell->getValue();
 cout << value << endl;

Comment: Rule of three....?

Comment: Why do you need a `Cell newcell` variable? You have a `Cell* cell`. Use it, don't make unneeded copies.

Comment: "extremely new to C++ and using pointers" Perhaps maybe try to do without pointers for a while? They are hard to use, low level language facility.

Comment: @n.m. I am trying to learn them for the course I am on

Comment: I have solved it will post the answer below